# how to preserve elastic indexes in minikube kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am running elastic & kibana in kubernetes, minikube environment locally. I want to preserve the elastic search indices across minikube restarts. It's not important to preserve the indices if the minikube vm is recreated.

How can I change the config so the search indices are stored in a persistent disk either in the vm or on my macbook host?

This is the existing config file for Elastic Search.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.1
        env:
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

Comment: You'll also want to use a `StatefulSet` for things like ES or Postgres, etc, because you want `node-0` to always regain `node-0`'s persistent volume claim when running "for real" (not minikube), and having stable DNS names (which comes for free with `StatefulSet`) makes clustering ES much, much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: elasticsearch
    # 8<-- snip -->8
    volumeMounts:
    - name: es-data
      mountPath: /var/lib/elasticsearch
  initContainers:
  - name: chown
    image: busybox:latest
    command:
    - chown
    - -R
    - "1000"  # or whatever your "elasticsearch" user-id is
    - /var/lib/elasticsearch
    volumeMounts:
    - name: es-data
      mountPath: /var/lib/elasticsearch
  volumes:
  - name: es-data
    hostPath:
      path: /some/path/in/minikube
```

That `initContainers` business is because the `hostPath` will in 99% of the cases be owned `0:0` but the elasticsearch docker image is `USER elasticsearch` (uid 1000, IIRC) and thus does not have permission to `chown` the directory that is volume mounted into the container. You'll need to run that `chown` command before starting elasticsearch, thus, the `initContainer`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, the mountpoint is what I missed  when I read about volumes. I got it working by setting the mountpath to `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` and hostPath to `/data/elasticsearch` which is already mapped by minikube I think, maybe even to the host ( I haven't checked). Also I didn't use the initContainers stuff, it seems to work okay in my laptop environment anyway. Cheers.